# Black screen after changing SID in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-server-2008-r2, sid

I am using [this guide](http://thaolv.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-sysprepexe-to-change-sid-in.html) and similair ones to change SID in Windows 2008 R2 running under VirtualBox. Unfortunately, after reboot I see only black screen saying "Setup is updating registry settings" and then system hangs with black screen and white mouse coursor on it. I tried googling but did not find any solution for it... Please help, we need to change SID to use image of Windows 2008 R2 through development team.

Answer (score 1):

found a solution.

The thing was in GuestAdditions iso not attached to virtual machine... After attaching it our SID was changed during 30 minutes, and all this time the screen remained black, so do not be afraid whoever faces it:) I assume that it took 30 minutes because we had plenty of software installed. Anyway, our issue is fixed now.